# How to check at compile time if a Swift module exists on the current project?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I would like to know if there is any **preprocessor command in Swift** to check if a module exists. I use CocoaPods dependency manager tool, and I would like to check **during compile time** so I can use it or I have to do a custom workaround.

It would be something like this:

```
#if module(SwiftyJSON)

#else

#endif
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A proposal ([SE-0075](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0075-import-test.md)) to introduce a `canImport` directive has been accepted, but it hasn't been implemented yet as of Swift 3.0.2/Swift 3.1 beta. The bug tracking the implementation is [SR-1560](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1560).

With the directive, you would be able to write something like this:

```
#if canImport(UIKit)
// UIKit-based code
#elseif canImport(Cocoa)
// OSX code
#else
// Workaround/text, whatever
#endif
```

PS: "preprocessor command" is not the correct terminology for Swift because Swift doesn't have a preprocessor.

Comment: SE-0075 is implemented in Swuft4.1

Answer (score -1):

When you compile or archive your app, it will only install the modules, methods and classes that it actually needs, based on the code you have written. So to my knowledge, there is no way to check if the module exists, because it shouldn't be possible to have it or not have it. In other words, either you have it, or you don't. Meaning you, as the developer, knows if you have the pod installed, or not, which is why there shouldn't be a way to check something at runtime, that is already pre-determined. May I ask why you wanna achieve this?

Comment: I am creating a library/pod. And I would like to offer more methods if the client project already uses a library (in this case SwiftyJSON). I don't want to add the SwiftyJSON as a dependency because it's not mandatory, it's like a helper library.

Comment: Hm interesting, I am actually really not sure then. I can understand why you'd wanna have such an if statement, but I think it doesn't work what you're trying to achieve, because it implies that you are writing and compiling code without knowing if the package is there, which is not gonna work in Xcode or anywhere else. Either your pod has a dependency so you can use and compile yours and your dependencies code, or you don't and you can not :)

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you mean, and it's true. I think Cocoapods solved this issue with Objective-C adding some global defines in the past (they were added to your project's headers no matter what), but with Swift modules it's not the case as you only import what you specify (anyway it would be an ugly approach). I guess I will have to create another pod just with the SwiftyJSON additions, as a subspec maybe.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, you can make one 'smaller pod' and one 'larger pod' with all the features, so your users can choose for themselves what they need

Comment: @Florensvb I need exactly same configuration.... How should larger pod communicate with smaller pod, without using if canImport() in the larger pod, to access methods from the smaller pods?